# Why does `auto` not adopt the constexpr'ness of its initializing expression?

Tags: c++, type-inference, constexpr, c++20, auto

Why doesn't defining a variable with `auto` keyword carry the `constexpr`'ness of the expression used to initialize it?

---

As an example, consider the following code:

```
#include <string_view>

constexpr std::string_view f() { return "hello"; }

static constexpr std::string_view g() {
    constexpr auto x = f(); // (*)
    return x.substr(1, 3);
}

int foo() { return g().length(); }
```

With GCC 10.2 and `--std=c++20 -fsanitize=undefined -O3`, this [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/brjM1n) into:

```
foo():
        mov     eax, 3
        ret
```

But if we remove the constexpr on line (*), we would get a 27-line program with a bunch of pointers, a long string constant etc.

Notes:

- I marked this question C++20, but I have no reason to believe this behavior is different from C++11's.
- This question is *not* about the example, it is about the general behavior of `auto` w.r.t. `constexpr`ness. The example simply shows that that GCC does not treat x as `constexpr` if we don't explicitly tell it to.

Comment: `auto` works the same was as templates do.  Top level const is ignored.  `constexpr` is never infered.

Comment: `constexpr` isn't part of the type system, it isn't something that can be deduced.

Comment: constexpr expression is not (guaranteed to be) evaluted in compile-time out of a constexpr context.  The effect of your sample is caused by compiler's optimization and it may not come with the default optimization level. Check this [sample](https://godbolt.org/z/Ya69TE).

Comment: @Barry: But it is 'deduced', when you want to use an expression in a constexpr context. So why not carry this feature over the auto along with that type?

Comment: @VainMan: Ok, but why isn't GCC required to treat `auto x = f()` just like `constexpr auto x = f()`?

Comment: @NathanOliver: I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you have `template <typename T> void foo(T)` and pass it a `const int`, `T` will be `int`, not `const int` as top level const is removed from the deduced type.  Same thing happens with `auto`.  It removes the `const`.

Comment: @einpoklum I am not an expert in the area of language-lawyer. But I think one of the reason is that only the used branches of constexpr function are required to be constant experssions while other branches not. For example, `constexpr int f(int a) {return a == 0 ? 42 : time(nullptr);}` is legal. if `auto x = f(0)` is required to be "deduced" as a constant expression, it must know the function body.

Comment: I get the same 3 line asm for `foo` with no `constexpr` here https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Mn7xEh

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: Huh! Well, actually, it seems that's because of the undefined behavior sanitizer. Weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`auto` is intended to enable type deduction, not a replacement for "everything useful you would have typed here". `constexpr` is not a part of an expression's type, and is thus ignored by `auto` (as opposed to `const` and `volatile`, which  are part of an expression's type, and are deduced).

---

> But if we remove the constexpr on line (*), we would get a 27-line program with a bunch of pointers, a long string constant etc.

That is a choice for your compiler. It has 100% of the information it needs to make that code go away. The fact that it didn't is not the C++ standard's concern.

This is a "quality of implementation" issue, not a standardization issue. If an implementation won't run as much of your code at compile-time as you desire, you can complain to them about it.

Remember: `constexpr` isn't meant to be a runtime optimization per-se. It's meant to allow you to write things that you otherwise couldn't write. Like `std::get<g()>(some_tuple)` or whatever. That code *has to run* at compile-time, since it's being used in a template parameter.

---

> I'm not asking about some kind of deep deduction, only about the case of the function explicitly being constexpr.

Let's forget for a moment that `auto` is for type deduction and `constexpr` is not part of the type system. Let's focus instead on what if `auto` was supposed to deduce `constexpr` anyway. So what you want is for `auto` to *only* deduce `constexpr` if `<expr>` is specifically a function that is designated `constexpr`.

So let's look at some code:

```
auto x = constexpr_func();
auto y = constexpr_func() + 5;
auto z = constexpr_func() + constexpr_func();
auto w = constexpr_func_2() + constexpr_func_2();
```

Which of these variables are `constexpr`? If what you want is what we had, then `x` would be `constexpr`, but `y` would not. I personally would find this both surprising and annoying.

Worse, if we assume `constexpr_func()` returns an `int`, then `z` is also not `constexpr`. But if `constexpr_func_2()` returns a user-defined literal type that has a `constexpr operator+`, then `w` *would be* `constexpr`.

Isn't that all very weird? So I highly suspect that this is not what you really want.

What you really want is for `auto x = <expr>;` to deduce `constexpr` if `constexpr auto x = <expr>;` would be valid.

But really, that goes back to the original point. If you make a variable `constexpr`, that should mean you want it to be used in a place where being `constexpr` is required by some process. Given that fact, deducing `constexpr` makes no sense, because you should *need* it to be `constexpr` lest you get a compile error.

Comment: "`constexpr` isn't meant to be a runtime optimization" this x100

Comment: I feel this answer is mostly restating the factual situation rather than the cause. What I'm wondering is why isn't `auto` carry the out-of-type-system information into the definition as well? Why should the compiler not be required to treat `auto x = constexpr_func();` as a constexpr variable? I'm not asking about some kind of deep deduction, only about the case of the function explicitly being constexpr.

Comment: @einpoklum Consider the different behavior you're suggesting for `auto a = 0;` and `int b = 0;` and how much code would break if `a` suddenly became `constexpr` here.

Comment: @einpoklum: "*What I'm wondering is why isn't auto carry the out-of-type-system information into the definition as well?*" Are you asking why a tool meant for type deduction doesn't deduce things that aren't part of the type system? Why should the compiler treat that specific case specially?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Ok, now I think I have my answer. I will slightly edit your answer to reflect what you said in the comment.

Comment: Also, I don't see where I implied I expect constexpr to be a runtime optimization.

Comment: @einpoklum: It's the part in your question where you cited that the problem was the presence/absence of code based on the use of `constexpr`. The only reason to care about what assembly the compiler generates is if you care about the performance of the program.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I used it only to "prove" that the compiler doesn't treat the variable as constexpr (in that, when you mark it as constexpr, it behaves differently).

Comment: @einpoklum: But it doesn't "behave differently"; it *compiles* differently. The behavior of the program is unchanged. The only reason to care about how it compiles is performance.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I meant, the compiler behaves differently, not the program.