# C++ usage of constexpr with lambda expression

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, constexpr

I was reading book [C++17 - The Complete Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/396730017X) and in the section 6.1 on `constexpr` lambda the author gives two examples:

```cpp
auto squared1 = [](auto val) constexpr { // example 1. compile-time lambda calls
  return val * val;
};
```

and

```cpp
constexpr auto squared2 = [](auto val) { // example 2. compile-time initialization
  return val * val;
};
```

and says that these two are different from each other in the sense that ***example 1*** is evaluated at compile time and ***example 2*** is initialized at compile time.

---

The author then makes the following statements which I don't understand completely:

> If (only) the lambda is `constexpr` it can be used at compile time, but
> If the (closure) object initialized by the lambda is `constexpr`, the
> object is initialized when the program starts but the lambda might
> still be a lambda that can only be used at run time (e.g., using
> static variables). Therefore, you might consider declaring:
>
> ```cpp
> constexpr auto squared = [](auto val) constexpr { // example 3
>   return val * val;
> };
> ```

What does the above statement mean exactly?

It is obvious that the `constexpr` keyword appears on initialization statement of `squared2` lambda object and on the lambda expression itself in ***example 3*** but I don't understand what is the advantage of this over ***example 1*** .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The thing is, that an `auto`-declared object does not adopt the `constexpr`'ness of its initializing expression, only its type; and `constexpr` is *not* part of that type. See:

[Why does `auto` not adopt the constexpr'ness of its initializing expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64500142/why-does-auto-not-adopt-the-constexprness-of-its-initializing-expression)

So, suppose I had:

```
auto five_squared = 25;
```

the value 25 is very much `constexpr`, i.e. it can be used at compile-time. And yet - `five_squared` will *not* be usable at compile-time. You would still need to indicate it is `constexpr` (*).

It's essentially the same with your lambda. A lambda is an instance of an on-the-spot-defined class with an `operator()`. Nothing about that would make `squared` be a `constexpr` variable if you don't make it one yourself.

---

<sub>(*) -  Note that because of a special rule in the C++ language, `const` integers that are initialized with a constant-expression are automatically `constexpr`, so you *could* just write `const auto` and get the `constexpr` implicitly. However, this is a tricky special-case to have to remember, so if you want to make a variable `constexpr` I recommend being explicit about it. Thanks goes to @cigien for bringing up this point.</sub>

Comment: That exception with integer is most confusing now that we have `constexpr`...

Comment: @Jarod42 Indeed, but I don't think there's a way to fix it going forward :(

Comment: @cigien: On the contrary: Because it's obscure and difficult-to-remember, I [believe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39068744/1593077) that people should simply not use it as an assumption at all.